# PHP function wont save variable

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

I have this php function that I created that is basically a switch statement. For each case, the $team_image variable is saved to a different value. It looks a little something like this:

```
function teamImage($team)
{
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":

            $team_image = "orioles";

        case "New York Yankees":

            $team_image = "yankees";

        case "Toronto Blue Jays":

            $team_image = "bluejays";
```

You get the idea. However, when I call on the function and try to use the $team_image variable in other parts of my code, it doesn't work because apparently, the variable is still undefined. any thoughts?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: There is not enough information to sufficiently answer this question. Please post how you plan to use the `$team_image` variable.

Comment: And although this doesn't seem to affect your problem, please remember the [break statement](http://php.net/break/) if you need it, which it seems like you will.

Comment: I disagree that there isn't enough information to answer the question. It is clear to me where the problem arises (from a lack of awareness of scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're only setting the `$team_image` inside the `teamImage` function, it will only exist with that function's "[scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)". (In general, variables, etc. will always exist in as narrow a scope as possible, which is good in terms of encapsulation. (Encapsulation being a key benefit of [object orientated programming](http://www.php.net/oop), etc. which you may go on to discover as you learn more.)

As such, you should return the `$team_image` value from the `teamImage` function and set it as follows:

```
function teamImage($team) {

    $team_image = NULL;

    switch($team) {
       ...
    }    

    return $team_image;
}

$team_image = teamImage($team);
```

An alternative would be to define the `$team_image` variable within the `teamImage` function as a global by adding the line  `global $team_image;` at the beginning of the function, but this isn't considered good practice.

Additionally, you should `break;` each case code block within your switch statement as otherwise you'll simply end up setting `$team_image` with the value assigned in your final case. (i.e.: If you don't break each statement, code flow will continue into the next.) See the [switch PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the $team_image variable is scoped to the function. Either declare $team_image as global at the beginning of the function:

```
function teamImage($team)
{ 
  global $team_image;
  ...
```

or better, return $team_image at the end of your function and assign it to another variable where you need it:

```
function teamImage($team) {
   ...
   return $team_image
}

...

$image = teamImage($team_name);
```

Comment: And the other posters are correct, you need to add a break after each of your case statements.

Answer (score 1):

**Few facts:**

- You've forgot [`break;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850671/php-function-wont-save-variable/5850714#5850714)
- **`$team_image` have local scope**
- Do you really don't want to use `default`?

**Answer:**

You have to use [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) in your function, **if you haven't used already**, otherwise the problem can be in `$team_image` [**scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

**Example:**

*Things changed:*

- `$team_image` [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- Added break in your [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)
- Finished function code (added return)

*Code:*

```
function teamImage($team)
{
    $team_image = '';
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":    
            $team_image = "orioles";
        break;

        case "New York Yankees":    
            $team_image = "yankees";
        break;

        case "Toronto Blue Jays":    
            $team_image = "bluejays";
        break;
    }
    return $team_image;
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
$team = 'new York Yankees';
$teamImage = teamImage($team); // yankees
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to see the variables scope documentation..[variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is one of variable **scope**. PHP functions have their own symbol table, and when you assign to the variable `$team_image` in your function, you're really assigning to a local variable. That variable goes 'out of scope' at the end of the function, meaning it doesn't exist any more.

The best way to fix this would probably be to **return** the value from the function and assign to the `$team_image` variable using the function call.

```
function teamImage($team)
{
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":

            return "orioles";

        case "New York Yankees":

            return "yankees";

        case "Toronto Blue Jays":

            return "bluejays";
    }
}

$team_image = teamImage($team);
```

Now the variable `$team_image` is in the scope in which you call the function.

If you want the variable to be visible in all scopes, you can use `$GLOBALS['team_image']` instead, but global variables are widely considered bad practice. (You can find many sources online that will explain why.)

Answer (score 0):

```
However, when I call on the function and try to use the $team_image variable in other parts of my code
```

you need to return your `$team_image` at the end of the function

so it looks like this

```
function getTeamImage($team)
{
 switch($team)
{
 case "a":
    $team_image = "asdas";
    break;
  #end so on
}

return $team_image;
}

#And than you can use in your other code:

$team_image = getTeamImage($team);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to use `break` in your switch to prevent [fall-through](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

http://codepad.org/CVzLAUr0

```
<?php

function teamImage($team)
{
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":
            $team_image = "orioles";
            break;
        case "New York Yankees":
            $team_image = "yankees";
            break;
        case "Toronto Blue Jays":
            $team_image = "bluejays";
            break;
        default:
            $team_image = "none";
    }
    return $team_image;
}

echo teamImage('Baltimore Orioles');

?>
```

Second, if you want to use a variable that is modified in a global scope, you need to use the `global` keyword within the function, or use the `$GLOBALS` array:

http://codepad.org/nkT5FxrH

```
<?php

$team_image = '';

function teamImage($team)
{
    global $team_image;
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":
            $team_image = "orioles";
            break;
        case "New York Yankees":
            $team_image = "yankees";
            break;
        case "Toronto Blue Jays":
            $team_image = "bluejays";
            break;
        default:
            $team_image = "none";
    }
    return $team_image;
}

teamImage('Baltimore Orioles');

echo $team_image;

?>
```